# Linker Error when upgrading to XCTest

Tags: build, xcode5, xctest, ios7.1

I've upgraded my project from sentest to xctest.

However I can't run tests because of the error:
building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture x86_64

Clearly there is a problem with the reference to the XCTest library, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Several similar questions refer to the Framework Search Paths which I have as follows:
    $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    $(inherited)
    $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)

Answer (score 0):

Had to answer my own one. -1 to stackoverflow.

What I was missing that there is a different target for tests.

When I switched to the tests target (there's an up and down target selector on the project settings page top left) I noticed that the paths where screwed up with extra / chars and " chars.